# Looking for a plug in for eclipse to draw state charts

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am using Java in eclipse, It would be wonderful if I could find a plug in which can draw state chart from a XML format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about plug-ins for Eclipse, but I'd recommend AT&T's graphviz as a terrific tool for easily rendering states and transitions.  The input format is not XML; however, it'd be trivial to read an XML file, generate the required format, and render it using graphviz.  Laszlo Szathmary has a nice Java class that lets you do it right inside a Java class - very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Eclipse's Graphical Editing Framework(GEF).  It should have everything you need.  http://www.eclipse.org/gef/overview.html